# Casting Generic type to base type

Tags: c#, generics

I have the next scenario:

```
public class RequestBase { }
public class ResponseBase { }

public interface IService<TRequest, TResponse>
           where TRequest : RequestBase where TResponse : ResponseBase
{
    TResponse Execute(TRequest request);
}

public class MyRequest : RequestBase { }
public class MyResponse : ResponseBase { }

public class MyService : IService<MyRequest, MyResponse>
{
    public MyResponse Execute(MyRequest request)
    {
        return new MyResponse();
    }
}
```

now i am creating factory that will create my service:

```
class ServicesFactory
{
    public IService<RequestBase, ResponseBase> Create()
    {
        var service = new MyService();
        return (IService<RequestBase, ResponseBase>)service;
    }    
}
```

The problem is that the casting throw exception.

How can I cast the derived type to the base type?

Comment: Could you add a tag for the language you're using? C# maybe?

Comment: If you are pushing everything around by the base classes there is no reason to use generics.  change your create or factory signature to include type parameters if you want static typing.  Otherwise you may as well just use object or the base types.

Comment: This is of course just a simplified example of my code but i do need this hierarchy

Answer (score 3):

Make your interface covariant on `TResponse`:

```
public interface IService<TRequest, out TResponse>
```

and you'll be able to convert `MyService` to `IService<MyRequest, ResponseBase>`. Note that it isn't possible to convert to `IService<RequestBase, ResponseBase>`, because not all `RequestBase`s are `MyRequest`s.

That said, you can decorate `MyService` with a different class that will check at runtime whether passed in `RequestBase` is actually `MyRequest`. This, of course, violates LSP if the interface expects any `RequestBase`.

Comment: i tried this but it didnt work. i also tried to add interface to my RequestBase and ResponseBase and then cast to IService<IRequestBase, IResponseBase> didnt work too. on both occasion i get exception

Unable to cast object of type 'Playground.MyService' to type 'Playground.IService`2[Playground.RequestBase,Playground.ResponseBase]'.

Comment: The `out` keyword denotes *co*variance (and the `out` keyword is correct here; the interface is indeed covariant over `TResponse`), not contravariance (which is denoted by the `in` keyword).

Comment: @Kyle Right, I always confuse them. Fixing.

Comment: @eitanby Read the rest of the answer: casting `MyService` to `IService<RequestBase, ResponseBase>` is illegal because *the former doesn't implement the latter*: you can't legally call `myService.Execute(new AnotherClassThatInheritsFromRequest())` which you can legally do with an instance of `IService<RequestBase, ResponseBase>`